# Find the limit of $P(\bar{X_n}\leq 1.8)$ for i.i.d random variables $X_i$s of known distribution

Tags: probability-theory, law-of-large-numbers

> Let $X_1,X_2,…$ be a sequence of independent and identically distributed random variables with
>   $P(X_1=1)=\frac{1}{4}$ and $P(X_1=2)=\frac{3}{4}$. If $\bar{X_n}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i$, for $n=1,2,\ldots$ then $\lim_{n\to \infty} P(\bar{X_n}\leq 1.8)$ is ?

**My work:**

We can write $P(\bar{X_n}\leq1.8)=1-P(\bar{X_n}\geq1.8)$,

so $\lim_{n\to \infty}P(\bar{X_n}\leq1.8)=1-\lim_{n\to \infty}P(\bar{X_n}\geq1.8)=1-P \{\lim_{n\to \infty}\bar{X_n}\geq 1.8\}$.

Now I have a feeling that we can apply *Weak law of large numbers*, but I don't know the mean. If it were the case then we could conclude that required probability is $1$. So how should I proceed next? Is this the right path? Help please. Thanks.

Comment: They gave you enough information to calculate the mean. But to answer your question, yeah you're on the right path.

Comment: What do you mean by "I don't know the mean"? Do you know how to compute the expectation of a random variable?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom yeah I do know how to calculate the expectation of a r.v. What I am saying is how to use the facts $P(X_1=1)$ and $P(X_1=2)$ to calculate it?

Comment: What is $\mathbb{E}(X_1)$? Note that the sums of probabilities is $P(X_1=1)+P(X_1=2)=1$.

Comment: @HarryPotter what formula are you used to using? What do you think is "missing" here?

Comment: We know the weak law of large numbers says $P\{|(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i)-\mu|\geq \epsilon\}\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$. @Omnomnomnom I am missing something, I need to find $\mu$ (if it is $0$ then the problem will be solved). Right? Now if I calculate $E(X_1)$ , can I conclude all other $E(X_i)$ has same exp since they are i.i.d ?

Comment: @i707107 $E(x_1)=1\times P(X=1)+2\times P(X=2)=1/4+3/2=7/4$ right?

Comment: @HarryPotter Yes. Then you can use the weak law of large numbers.

Comment: Uh makes sense now. Thank you @i707107

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\overline{X}_n=\frac74$ and $\mathrm{Var}\left(X_n\right)=\frac3{16n}$, we have by [Chebyshev's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev's_inequality),
$$
P\left(\left|X_n-\tfrac74\right|\ge\lambda\right)\le\frac3{16n\lambda^2}
$$
Plugging in $\lambda=\frac1{20}$ yields
$$
P\left(X_n\ge1.8\right)\le\frac{75}{n}
$$
Therefore,
$$
P\left(X_n\le1.8\right)\ge1-\frac{75}{n}
$$

Comment: Ok I understood everything but one point, how $P\left(\left|X_n-\tfrac74\right|\ge\lambda\right)$ become $P(X_n\geq 1.8)$ after putting $\lambda=1/20$?

Comment: Got it thanks .

Comment: $\left\{x:x\ge1.8\right\} \subset\left\{x:\left|x-\frac74\right|\ge\frac1{20}\right\}$